# Scaling has no effect in Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, transforms, soft-body

I scaled an object up in Object mode, but when I start the game engine it returns to a much smaller size. This occurs when the object is a Soft Body, when I set it back to Static or to Rigid Body for physics it scales properly in the engine.

I have tried clicking the "Apply Transformation" button in Rigid Body Tools under the Physic tab in the object toolbar but it doesn't have a noticeable effect. (There isn't a Soft Body tools that I can find).

Is there a way to have scaling work for a soft body or do I need to go back and create a new larger mesh?